# prettyPhoto duplicates first image from contenthover (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, image, duplicates, prettyphoto

I've spent hours and hours trying to solve this problem, but I've found no solution.
I'm new in javascript, so there are lots of things I don't really comprehend. I'm basically making sort of a Frankenstein code, but it's all been working fine. Until I implemented contenthover...

Here's the thing: I'm building a website in Dreamweaver using prettyPhoto and contenthover. In one page I have both plugins working. I need a button to trigger prettyPhoto from contenthover, and it does actually, but for some reason the first image in the gallery is duplicated. It's really weird, because before implementing contenthover everything was okay. (I have two triggers for the same gallery, and they worked OK until contenthover).

I'm sure there's gotta be a way to solve this problem, but it's beyond my acknowledge.

(My native language is spanish, so I may or may not be writing something wrong... hehe)

Thanks so much in advance... I hope someone can help me!

Oh and my code is

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
            theme:'light_rounded',
            social_tools:false,
            deeplinking:false,
            <!-- Temas : light_square, light_rounded, dark_square, dark_rounded, facebook-->

    });
});


$(function(){
    $('.myimage').contenthover({
        overlay_background:'#000',
        overlay_opacity:0.8,
        overlay_width:200,
        overlay_height:200,
        onshow: function(){
                $('[rel^="prettyPhoto"]').prettyPhoto({'theme': 'light_rounded',social_tools:false, deeplinking:false,});
    },
        onhide: function(){
                $('[rel^="prettyPhoto"]').prettyPhoto({'theme': 'light_rounded',social_tools:false, deeplinking:false,});
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two explicit links/triggers to the same image using rel='prettyPhoto', it will show that image twice in the gallery. To resolve this, you can do something like this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452778/jquery-prettyphoto-open-gallery-from-a-link-thats-not-an-image):

```
<button id="startPrettyPhoto">Open Gallery</button>
```

Then in your javascript section, add:

```
$("#startPrettyPhoto").click(function() {
  $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']:first").click()
});
```